# Почему не применяется стиль для CheckBox в Android?

Tags: java, android

В созданном стиле все что возможно установил белым, чтобы наверняка

```
 <style name="checkBoxStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/clrWhite</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/clrWhite</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/clrWhite</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/clrWhite</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/clrWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/clrWhite</item>
</style>
```

Применил

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_rsr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
/>
```

но стиль не применяется.

В манифесте для этой Activity прописано следующее:

```
<activity
   android:name=".aLogo"
   android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
   android:theme="@style/LogoTheme" 
/>
```

Стиль:

```
<style name="LogoTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/logo_splash</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/clrRed</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/clrRed</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/clrRed</item>
</style>
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Приведите хотя бы пример того, что получилось. В виде картинки.

Comment: CheckBox остается без изменений, черная оконтовка квадрата, а в активном состоянии почему-то закрашен зеленым.

Comment: Наверное это не поможет, но зачем вам </Checkbox>? Добавьте / перед закрывающей скобкой чекбокса. Вот так: <Checkbox ....some code... />

Comment: Исправил, но это не принципиально.

Comment: а если убрать тему в активности и оставить только стиль у чекбокса?

Comment: я не знаю почему, но после пересборки проекта все заработало. Благодарю всех!!! Вопрос закрыт.